# Accessing stream data for pages using Application Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebresponse

Hi I am building an app for a company that has several official facebook pages for products.  In the app we want to display all the official page posts for those pages in a news feed.  How can I query fb using the application access token instead of as a user?  I get an error when I try the below query stating that read stream permissions need to be granted.

"Queries for multiple source_ids require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission"

```
string _requestURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_id, message, permalink, likes, actor_id, comments, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id in (1,2,3, 4)  AND actor_id  in (1,2,3, 4) AND message != '' LIMIT 100&format=json&access_token=appID|AppSecret";
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: As stated, does the access token have the read_stream permissions ? You can specify the different permissions needed for the access token. If you have doubts, you can paste the access token in the linter tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and verify.

Comment: If I run the queries seperately and concatenate the results it works just fine.

Comment: It's a current limitation in queries that contain more than one source_id when using an app access token.